# É possivel usar o Babel via CDN?

Tags: javascript, babel

Estou fazendo um projeto (App em `JS` + `Cordova`), e me deparei com um problema ao utilizar `let`, `const`, `arrow function` e etc (Só funciona em aparelhos mais modernos, Como, `Android 6+` ou `IOS 10+)`.

Entao queria saber se é possivel utilizar o `Babel` via CDN, ou de outra forma, porque, ate entao, nao achei muito coisa falando sobre o uso dele, dessa maneira.

Comment: Se usas Cordova tens um pipeline Node.js certo? o melhor seria juntar o Babel aí, para compilar o JavaScript. O Cordova tem certamente algo configurável para isso.

Comment: @Sergio Seria isso? https://github.com/kerrishotts/cordova-plugin-webpack-transpiler

Comment: Provavelmente esse dá. Mas pode haver outro(s) que usem o babel diretamente, sem o webpack. O webpack dá-te possibilidade de mais funcionalidades caso precises no futuro. Esse plugin parece-me pouco popular ainda.

Comment: Provavelmente podes também compilar o JS separado do Cordova e dizer ao Cordova para ir buscar o ficheiro compilado.